# Why include directores of linked libraries are not correctly propagated?

Tags: cmake

I have a lib myTest that links against myFoo which again links against myBar.

myTest -> myFoo -> myBar

I have the following setup:

###### CMakeLists.txt of myTest lib

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

add_library(myTest STATIC)

target_sources(myTest 
    INTERFACE
        FILE_SET HEADERS
        BASE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myTest/test_file.h
)

target_link_libraries(
  PUBLIC
    myFoo
)

...
```

###### CMakeLists.txt of myFoo lib

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

add_library(myFoo STATIC)

target_sources(myFoo
    INTERFACE
        FILE_SET HEADERS
        BASE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myFoo/a.h
)

target_link_libraries(
  PUBLIC
    myBar
)

target_include_directories(myFoo INTERFACE
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myFoo>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/myFoo>
)

...
```

###### CMakeLists.txt of myBar

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

add_library(myBar STATIC)

target_sources(myBar
    INTERFACE
        FILE_SET HEADERS
        BASE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myBar/my_bar_class.h
)

target_include_directories(myFoo INTERFACE
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myBar>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/myBar>
)

...
```

Inside the source `test_file.h` of `myTest` lib, there is an `#include "myBar/my_bar_class.h"`, but when I built the code I get an error, that the file "myBar/my_bar_class.h" can't be found or read.

I thought using `target_link_libraries` would pull all PUBLIC / INFERFACE marked include directories also into the lib it is linked against. This doesn't seem to be the case. When I print the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of myTest then only the include directories of myTest and myFoo are listed.

What am I actually doing wrong here? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: With the header at `include/myBar/my_bar_class.h` the directive `#include "myBar/my_bar_class.h"` works only when `include` is listed as an include directory. The include directory `include/myBar` does NOT resolve this directive (because there is no file at path `include/myBar` + `myBar/my_bar_class.h` = `include/myBar/myBar/my_bar_class.h`).

Comment: You are totally right. But even if I change the include to only be the file itself `my_bar_class.h`, the error is still the same one.

Comment: Then, "Inside the source test_file.h of myTest lib ..." - `test_file.h` is NOT a source file, it is a header file (it has `.h` extension). Header files are not compiled standalone but only as a part of source files (`.c` extension or some other). And exactly source files are determine which include directories are accessible during the compilation. So, which exact **source file** (`.c`) you compile when get the error inside a `test_file.h`? That information should be contained in the error message. Please, show (add to the question post) the **complete error message**.